# What files to keep under version control in Flash/AS3 project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, version-control, flashdevelop

I have this project called *Foo* with the following structure but what files should I exclude from version control? I build it with FlashDevelop.

```
├── bin                    <-- already in
│   └── Foo.swf            <--   .gitignore
├── css.xml
├── lib
│   └── as3corelib.swc
├── locales
│   ├── de_DE
│   │   └── ...
│   └── en_US
│       └── ...
├── obj                    <-- what
│   ├── FooConfig.old      <--   about
│   └── FooConfig.xml      <--     these?
├── src
│   ├── com
│   │   └── ...
│   └── printf.as
├── Foo.as3proj
└── Foo.report             <-- and this one?
```

I noticed that the files under `obj/` and the `report` file is changed by every build. So I guess I could exclude them?

**Foo.report** (10146 lines)

```
<report>
  <scripts>
    <script name="/home/max/Projects/flash-compiler/apache-flex-sdk/frameworks/libs/framework.swc(mx.graphics:GradientStroke)" mod="1422002215000" size="3188" optimizedsize="1400">
      <def id="mx.graphics:GradientStroke" />
      <pre id="mx.graphics:GradientBase" />
      <pre id="mx.graphics:IStroke" />
      <dep id="flash.display:GraphicsGradientFill" />
      <dep id="flash.display:Graphics" />
      <dep id="flash.display:CapsStyle" />
      <dep id="AS3" />
      <dep id="flash.display:GraphicsStroke" />
      <dep id="flash.geom:Rectangle" />
      <dep id="mx.core:mx_internal" />
      <dep id="flash.geom:Point" />
      <dep id="flash.display:JointStyle" />
    </script>
    <!-- more scripts are following here -->
  </scripts>
  <external-defs>
    <ext id="flash.events:AsyncErrorEvent" />
    <ext id="RegExp" />
    <!-- more exts are following here -->
  </external-defs>
</report>
```

**obj/FooConfig.old** begins with ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This Adobe Flex compiler configuration file was generated by a tool.-->
<!--Any modifications you make may be lost.-->
<flex-config>
  <target-player>11.2</target-player>
  <benchmark>false</benchmark>
  <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
  <compiler>
    <define append="true">
      <name>CONFIG::debug</name>
```

**obj/FooConfig.xml** begins with ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--This Adobe Flex compiler configuration file was generated by a tool.-->
<!--Any modifications you make may be lost.-->
<flex-config>
  <target-player>11.2</target-player>
  <benchmark>false</benchmark>
  <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
  <compiler>
    <define append="true">
      <name>CONFIG::debug</name>
```

Comment: I use FlashDevelop, but I don't know what `obj`/`FooConfig.old` and `FooConfig.xml` is.

Comment: @Aaron I added the first lines of these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `.as`, `.swc`, `.xml`, `.as3proj` and all other resources (images, sound, etc.) under source control. Anything under `bin` or `obj` folders can be ignored - those are generated by the compiler during a build.

I don't know what the `.report` file is - I haven't had one in FlashDevelop. I assume it's a compiler report file for verbose builds but I'm not sure. If you haven't created it, it's not likely to be needed for source control.

Comment: If you post your `.report` file, I'll take a look to be sure - I don't think it's necessary. I don't have FlashDevelop on this machine so I can't check right now.

Comment: @dAnjou It looks like a compiler report. I don't think it's needed - my projects don't have one. There's a compiler report setting somewhere in project properties.